# 240v Welding Outlet Right Near Breaker Box

Tags: electrical, 240v

I have a garage where I want to install a 240V / 50A outlet. The garage is finished with drywall. I want to place the outlet adjacent to the outside breaker box (but inside).

Questions:

1. What wires can I use? Wire calculator says 8 gauge. I have some 6/6/8 individual wires left over from another project (thhn/thwn). Can I use that?
2. I need conduit from the breaker box to the outlet box, correct? Is there a difference if I use individual wires vs. Romex? What size conduit would you use?
3. The parts I think I need are below. Anything you would change or add?
4. I would envision installing the outlet box on a stud - do I need to do any reinforcement of the box on the non-stud/drywall side?
5. Any other considerations?

About the install:

1. Square D box; have the quad breaker will use to replace an existing tandem
2. Will use NEMA 6-50 welding outlet
3. Square D box outside on wall of garage
4. Will want to install the outlet opposite and slightly below the breaker box on inside of garage
5. Garage finished with drywall
6. Length of run under 4 feet - may be less than 2

Parts needed (?):
Conduit end 1
Conduit end 2
Conduit (check size)
Outlet box
Outlet cover
Outlet
Wire x3 (or Romex?)
Bonding wire (green)
Bonding screw

Comment: Most places with a recent code edition adopted you'll need a two-pole 50a **GFCI** breaker since the outlet is in a garage.

Comment: Thanks ecnerwal - had no idea on that. It looks like that is very likely the case. I can use a 50/50 gfci if I can ever get a 230230 square d.

Answer (score 3):

The normal rule is "anything outside can't be Romex". However, exceptions are often made for a box that is on the outside wall. In your case, take a look at the other wires coming out of the breaker panel. If a large number of them are indeed typical Romex (typically 15A white, 20A yellow) then you will probably be OK using non-metallic cable (common brand name is Romex) for your welder receptacle.

As far as wires, the usual answer is to check an [ampacity table](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/) which shows:

- 6 AWG copper cable
- 8 AWG copper wires
- 6 AWG aluminum wires

Aluminum is normally a lot cheaper, but for just a few feet it generally doesn't matter much. Breakers can normally connect to copper or aluminum with no problem. However, many receptacles are copper only, and that should be the assumed default if you don't see it in the specifications.

For conduit size you go to a [conduit full calculator](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-conduit). It looks like 3/4" or 1" depending on the type of conduit. Larger is always OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the THHN, but that will need to be in conduit.
With Romex, you could potentially run it directly out of the back of the box into the wall cavity, down the cavity and into the new box.  For this you would not need to use conduit.

Personally, that's what I would do.
I would put the new receptacle into a wall cavity that the panel has direct access to it.
Cut the hole for your new box (using an "old work" plastic box).  Buy the more expensive option (more on this below).
Feed the Romex though the panel into the cavity, pull the Romex out through the hole.
Feed the Romex through the box, then secure the box into the hole.  I suggest using a box that can be screwed directly into the adjacent stud.  You shouldn't need any additional support if you do this.
Connect both ends of the Romex.
Button it all up.

As far as the box that you are using, there are several quality levels of old-work boxes. You get what you pay for. The cheaper ones are more flexible and have less robust mounting options. The "more expensive option" will be stiffer and have more secure mounting options. If you were putting in a light switch, go for the cheap one. Since this box will hold a heavy duty receptacle, you'll want the better box.

I like these boxes:
https://www.southwire.com/electrical-components/non-metallic-boxes-covers/two-gang-non-metallic-romex-box-38-cu-in-/p/MSB2G

And technically, you probably need a permit to do this, but that's between you and your local goverment.

Comment: What does "Buy the more expensive option." mean?

Comment: @FreeMan There are several quality levels of old-work boxes.  You get what you pay for.  The cheaper ones are more flexible and have less robust mounting options.  The "more expensive option" will be stiffer and have more secure mounting options.  If you were putting in a light switch, go for the cheap one.  Since this box will hold a heavy duty receptacle, you'll want the better box.

Comment: You might want to [edit] that into your answer to make it more clear for everyone. Also, while I understand "more" v "less" flexible, you might want to define what the more/less robust mounting options are.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have THHN/THWN in suitable size, conduit makes sense.

Flexible metallic conduit (FMC) is probably the easiest one as there's no fuss with bending it to fit just so. EMT or Rigid/IMC might be easy if you can arrange the two boxes to either be a straight shot or to suit pre-formed offsets or sweeps rather than having to get into bending your own, if you're not equipped for that.

Actually, this is all inwall so Electical Nonmetallic Tubing (ENT) ("smurf tube") would also be a conduit option that's flexible.